# Compiling FreeRDP Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, software-installation, compiling, software-sources

total Ubuntu noob here but I did try searching this forum and I couldn't find an answer to my question.
I'm following [this guide](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation) on installing FreeRDP from source and I've run into a roadblock after entering the `sudo make install`command in my terminal. I've interpreted the excerpt

> Now create /etc/ld.so.conf.d/freerdp.conf and add the following line to it:
>   `/usr/local/lib/freerdp`

to mean `mkdir /etc/ld.so.conf.d/freerdp.conf/usr/local/lib/freerdp`
Yet when I input this commmand, I get the following error:

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/ld.so.conf.d/freerdp.conf/usr/local/lib/freerdp’: No such file or directory

Can anyone explain to me what to do next? Am I even interpreting the directions correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *directory* `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` should already exist: either use an editor to create the *file*

```
sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/freerdp.conf
```

and then enter the text `/usr/local/lib/freerdp`, save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and close (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>); or use the command

```
echo '/usr/local/lib/freerdp' | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/freerdp.conf
```